# Setting up Windows Authentication (Kerberos) in Google Chrome in Docker for Selenium project

Tags: docker, selenium, kerberos

I'm building a web API in .NET Core 3.1 that is using Selenium with Google Chrome driver that performs various tasks such as visiting a website and taking a screenshot. The websites it visits may also hit other internal web APIs that require windows authentication to access. The API is deployed through Docker (Linux) and Kubernetes.

Locally, everything works with no issues - it is able to access all our internal websites, even ones that require Windows authentication. When deployed, it can no longer access the websites that have APIs that require Windows authentication - it receives an Unauthorized error, but it can still access other websites and works fine otherwise.

I've tried multiple ways to try to get this to work properly

- Various Chrome driver options: explicit and * white listing
- Overriding Chrome policy to add whitelist options (http://akasurde.github.io/krb-auth-chrome.html)
- Adding a Chrome user so it doesn't run as root

What's the correct way to set this up and get working properly? I'm not 100% how the Kerberos keytabs were set up for the Docker container, but I can ask about specifics if it's relevant to solving this.

Using

1. Selenium version 4.0.0-alpha07
2. Google Chrome version 87
3. Google Chrome driver version 87.0.4280.20 for Linux
4. Chrome driver option arguments: "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--allow-running-insecure-content", "--disable-web-security", "--auth-server-whitelist=*", "--auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist=*", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"
5. Docker container base is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1, downloading/installing Google Chrome, its drivers separately, plus some internal commands

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be facing the same issue, this was happening when accessing apis deployed on Docker (Linux) on Kestrel, Kerberos was doing a reverse dns lookup without success.

The solution was to add reverse dns records on the docker/kubernetes environment so it was able to successfully do that look up and continue with the Kerberos handshake.

Comment: am I getting this right that Kerberos was trying to do a reverse DNS lookup of the API address? did you just add a /etc/hosts entry to resolve this issue?